# Would an observer going faster than the speed of light in a vacuum be able to observe photons that they emit?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, speed-of-light, observers, faster-than-light

If I could exceed the speed of light in a vacuum, would I be able to see photons that I previously emitted?

Would this be theoretically possible?

Comment: How can you cross a speed? Do you mean crossing a light beam?

Comment: yes, maybe the beam also..
the velocity/speed of light is  300,000 km/s. if I cross this number, such as 300,000+ km/s.. what would happen? would I see the quantum of light?

Comment: Well first from a theoretical perspective you cannot reach this speed at all, as this would require an infinite energy. There is an interesting video that show light propagation in slow motion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snSIRJ2brEk

Comment: okey thanks.. but i say "if" a "Hypothesis"

Comment: I reread your sentence, you added a plus to the speed. If your hypothesis means to go faster than the speed of light in vacuum, your hypothesis is just unrealistic and you cannot ask it here.

Comment: before, most of the hypothesis were unrealistic but we, people made them real.
now a days people's think of imagination become so bookish and narrow based.
i just wanted to know how people thinking extensively about this question. :")

Comment: Welcome to SE.Physics!  I reworded your question a bit to help use standard language.  Please feel free to [edit] it or rollback my edit if it doesn't match your intent.

Comment: Just to note it, you can already see photons that you've previously emitted, e.g. by looking at your hand.  I'm assuming that you instead mean to ask if photons that you've previously emitted could "_catch up_" to you if you slow down?  Or something like that?  If you could clarify a bit, it'd probably help.

Comment: @Nat: the OP seemed to talk about the speed of light in the vacuum, not just the speed of light, which can be slowed down in a medium. I'm saying that because of your edit. The title is not complete, nor the rest.

Comment: @Exocytosis Please feel free to [edit] it if you think the title or the rest of it can be improved.  While I agree that they probably mean the speed of light in a vacuum, I typically understand people to imply the "_in a vacuum_" qualifier unless context would suggest otherwise.  Still, someone +1'd your comment, so if the explicit qualification would help promote clarity, I'd fully support it!

Comment: @Nat: Thank you, I just did. I was just afraid an unrealistic proposal could be understood as a more realistic one, which the OP clearly does not want to hear about.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your comments show that you mean going faster than the speed of light in a vacuum, so the answer to your question is no, this is not theoretically possible.

Comment: then i wouldn't see the quantum of light ? right?

Comment: No but only because you cannot do this experiment at all in the first place, not even in theory.